# Duplicate Values in DropDown C#

Tags: c#, dropdown

In a dropdown I've got a list of country of this type:
Text: "Italy" Value :"IT"
I need a copy of one of the country in the top of the list referred to the current language of the portal I'm working in, so the user can both select the first or the one into the list. Is just a hint we can say.
So I've just added a copy in this way:

```
cmbNazione.Items.Insert(0, cmbNazione.Items.FindByText(valori.Rows[0]["M_SOAAuthorityCountry"].ToString().ToUpper()));}
```

This code works fine. I got my duplicate value and I can select it without problem.

I am stuck when I already have a country that I have to set into the dropDown.
I just wrote that:

```
cmbNazione.Items.Insert(0, cmbNazione.Items.FindByText(valori.Rows[0]["M_SOAAuthorityCountry"].ToString().ToUpper()));
cmbNazione.ClearSelection();
cmbNazione.Items.FindByText(valori.Rows[0]["M_SOAAuthorityCountry"].ToString().ToUpper()).Selected = true;
```

The problem is that I receive the error: Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.
In fact if I check I got both the list Items (first, and the identical in the list) with the prop : selected = true. If I try to make one false both change to false. I cannot use them separately. 
I can't understand why I can use them correctly when I select manually, as a user, but not when I try to select them through code.
I also tried something like :

```
cmbNazione.SelectedIndex = cmbNazione.Items.IndexOf(cmbNazione.Items.FindByText(valori.Rows[0]["M_SOAAuthorityCountry"].ToString().ToUpper()));
```

But nothing. I'll every time have multiple items in the list of the selected

Comment: I don't think you ever have duplicates in the drop down box.  What you think is the duplicate is just the SELECTED Item.

Comment: You're choosing to make the item selected based on the TEXT value of the dropdown item.  The behavior you're seeing is because two entries have the same TEXT value, so both are being marked as selected.  You need to revisit why you are making a duplicate, if you want the first entry to be a default, have some logic to move that default to the first list element.  If you want a duplicate, you need to use a method other than FindByText in order to mark it as selected.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a duplicate value as it will confuse the user (if the value is on 2-3 position already) and architecture as retrieval may lead to 2 values being selected.

Your use case seem like you are offering the most commonly used value as the first one and then the remaining. If this is the case, follow the approach outlined below.

Find the ListItem required, then remove it from the list and add on the 1st position. Then mark it as selected.

```
var preferredItem = cmbNazione.Items.FindByText(...);
if (preferredItem != null) {
   cmbNazione.Items.Remove(preferredItem);
   cmbNazione.Items.Insert(0, preferredItem);
   cmbNazione.SelectedItemIndex = 0;
}
```

This way, there will be single item being selected and preserve the sanctity of the item (underlying value etc) while still allowing user to have the preferred one on top of list. You can chose to have this as 'pre-selected' or let user select it explictly.